# Struggling on second to last part deriving linear discriminant function

Tags: linear-algebra, discriminant-analysis

From this post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259174/the-discriminant-function-in-linear-discriminant-analysis/352085?noredirect=1#comment756950_352085) I am struggling with the matrix multiplication to get from:

$\log \pi _{k} - \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu _k)^T{\sum }^{-1}(x-\mu _k)$

to

$\log \pi _{k} - \frac{1}{2}[x^{T}{\sum }^{-1}x +\mu _k^{T}{\sum }^{-1}\mu _k] + x^{T}{\sum }^{-1}\mu _k$

I get the first two tersm but I struggle with the last term because when I do the foil multiplication I get:

$- \frac{1}{2}[(x^{T}{\sum }^{-1}x +\mu _k^{T}{\sum }^{-1}\mu _k)  - (x^{T}{\sum }^{-1}\mu _k + \mu _k^{T}{\sum }^{-1}x)  ]$

I don't see how the last two terms are the same? Why do we say: 
$-(x^{T}{\sum }^{-1}\mu _k$ + $\mu _k^{T}{\sum }^{-1}x)$ = $-2\cdot x^{T}{\sum }^{-1}\mu _k$

Comment: Is it on purpose that some x's are capital letters?

Comment: You’re right they should be lower case.  I will try to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to show that
$$
x^\top \Sigma^{-1} \mu_k = \mu_k^\top \Sigma^{-1} x.
$$
Indeed,
$$\begin{align}
x^\top \Sigma^{-1} \mu_k & = (x^\top \Sigma^{-1} \mu_k)^\top \\
& = \mu_k^\top (\Sigma^{-1})^\top x \\
& = \mu_k^\top \Sigma^{-1} x,
\end{align}$$
where the first equality follows from the fact that scalars are invariant to transposes and the third from the fact that $\Sigma$ (and hence $\Sigma^{-1}$) is symmetric.

Comment: How is the first equality true?  Seems like you just wrapped left side in a transpose?  I get the rest.

Comment: As was remarked at the end, Brian, transposing a scalar does nothing to it and $x^\prime\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k$ is a scalar.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now thanks.